# tkinter - Bind a different <Enter> event to each row in Treeview widget

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to create a unique, small tooltip window to appear when I hover over each row of a `Treeview` widget.

I can't work out how to bind `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events to each row uniquely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to `<Enter>` or `<Leave>`. You can use `<Motion>` instead:
This code is a modified version of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611611/how-to-change-row-color-when-mouse-over-tkinter-treeview)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, ttk


def highlight_row(event):
    tree = event.widget
    item = tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if tree.item(item,'text')!='':
        lbl.config(text=tree.item(item,'text'))
        lbl.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)
    else:
        lbl.place_forget()
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "remove", "highlight")
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "add", "highlight", item)

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, style = 'W.TButton')
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

tree.tag_configure('highlight', background='lightblue')
tree.bind("<Motion>", highlight_row)
lbl=Label(root,bg="white")
for i in range(100):
    tree.insert("", "end", text=f"Item #{i+1}")
    tree.tag_bind(i, '<Motion>', highlight_row)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my problem with the `<Motion>` event. However, it was quite a lot simpler than the way it is used in the question you referenced.